# Razor syntax: code block inside for each not working

Tags: razor

I'm struggling making the following razor snippet working

```
<ul>
@foreach (var lang in umbraco.cms.businesslogic.language.Language.GetAllAsList())
{
    var url = Model.Content.Url + "?lang=" + @lang.CultureAlias;

    if (currentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals(lang.CultureAlias))
    {
        <li class="active"><a href="@url">@lang.FriendlyName</a></li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li><a href="@url">@lang.FriendlyName</a></li>
    }
}
```

If I remove the variable assignment between the foreach and the if it works fine, but otherwise I get a compilation error (like the razor parser understands a } as markup and tries to render it).
Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think the issue is in this line

```
var url = Model.Content.Url + "?lang=" + @lang.CultureAlias;
```

You don't need the additional `@` since you are already in 'code' mode

So try changing `@lang.CultureAlias` to `lang.CultureAlias`

Answer (score 1):

You've got too many `@`s here:

```
var url = Model.Content.Url + "?lang=" + @lang.CultureAlias;
```

should become:

```
var url = Model.Content.Url + "?lang=" + lang.CultureAlias;
```

Comment: Well, if this helped you resolve the problem you were encountering you might consider marking it as answer, especially when this answer is provided 2 minutes before the answer that you actually marked as answer.

Comment: They are both the same answer, and that one was on top